# Python SSH Client

Tags: python, ssh

I need simple user interactive ssh client on python.
More specific, just singe-session cli for user(not automated command execution, but user-interactive console).
I tried paramiko, but recv_ready() sometimes work strange and not triggered until i send something to device. Putty as standalone clien works fine, so trouble is im my code.

```
def cli_connect(ip, channel_type='backup'):
host = 'ip address'
user = 'login'
secret = 'pass'
port = 22

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=secret, port=port)
ch = client.invoke_shell()
try:
    r_cmd = False #
    ch.send(' ')
    time.sleep(0.5)    
    jump = 'command for jump from root devise to target device via ssh, direct connection not supported'
    ch.send(jump)
   
    
    while True:
        if ch.recv_ready():
            inp_buffer = ch.recv(1).decode()
            if (r_cmd is True) & (inp_buffer != '\n'): #stripping user inp from output by flag end eof symbol
                continue
            if r_cmd is True and inp_buffer == '\n':
                r_cmd = False
            print(inp_buffer, sep='', end='')
            continue
        if keyboard.read_key() == 'space': #crutch for 1-tap sending blank when output stops mid-sentence
            ch.send(' ')

        if keyboard.read_key() != 'space':
            cmd = input()
            if cmd == 'stop it':
                return
            ch.send(cmd + '\n')
            r_cmd = True #flag for stripping user input from cli output (im avoiding input duplication for clean output)
            time.sleep(0.5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nEXIT\n')
    return
```

Comment: could the `keyboard` have a pending queue of keys that's causing it to hit `cmd = input()` immediately?

Comment: I guess it is not the case, i commented keyboard part, but wierd output freezes still present.

Answer (score -1):

Python needed a native (semi) GUI SSH Client

If anyone is interested in a FOSS ssh client for windows (soon linux too), I've published a new PyPi (Python). it's multitabbed, has stored/encrypted creds, saved sessions in a simple file you can backup, edit, share reuse etc.. themed light/dark and a mix. Its intended for network engineers who manage switches and routers a lot, but work fine on most anything. Please take it for a test spin if your interested. This is a first release, but is really very usable and friendly. There are a lot of opensource SSH Gui's out there, but Python was lacking, so I wrote one. Its not a wrapper of WebSSH, its much more native than that. https://github.com/scottpeterman/UglyPTY is the source, or just to install and kick the tires: all you need is python 3.9 or higher and "pip install uglypty" https://pypi.org/project/uglypty/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34868509)